# Calling form controls from a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am stuck in a deep problem right now. Plz help me with this....

I created a FORM call it form1. It contains a textbox T1. I started it running...
inside form1 there is a thread running which does some process P which is a member of a different CLASS call it class2.
To run the process P, I need a value from textbox T1. HOW DO I DO THAT?

Let me tell you, what I tried already.
I created instance of form1 in class2, and then tried to read textbox (T1) value. But that was empty, I figured out that reason.... rest, I tried with the property... Again failed...

PLZ help me with this. I am stuck since hours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Assuming Class1 is the class which does some process in thread. Create the property which corresponds to type of your main form. In this case, its called Form1. 



     class Class1
        {
    //his is the property
            public Form1 MyMainForm { get; set; }

            public  void    ShowText()
            {

//here the control is accesses 
//((TextBox)MyMainForm.Controls.Find("textBox1",true)[0])
                MessageBox.Show(((TextBox)MyMainForm.Controls.Find("textBox1",true)[0]).Text);
            }
        }

    im assuming ShowText() method is called on new thread, when button is clicked.

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    //craete instance of class1
                Class1 c = new Class1();
    //set the  property            
    c.MyMainForm = this;
    //start the method is new thread
                ThreadStart ts=new ThreadStart(c.ShowText);
                Thread t=new Thread(ts);
                t.Start();
            }
```

Comment: That is what my question is.... How do I access the controls of the thread which created it, that is the MAIN THREAD in this case. I am sorry, I am being annoyingly stupid...

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example to point you in the right direction. As mentioned in another answer you might have to Invoke to prevent cross-thread exceptions.

Inside your class named **FORM** add a method or property:

```
public string GetTextboxContent()
{
    return textbox.Text;
}
```

Change your **class2** to something like this:

```
class class2
{
    private MyForm m_form;

    public class2(MyForm form)
    {
        m_form = form;
    }

    public void DoThreadStuff()
    {
        string value = m_form.GetTextboxContent();
    }
}
```

You said "I created instance of form1 in class2, and then tried to read textbox (T1) value. But that was empty": Don't create a new instance: Pass the existing instance to **class2**!

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi Yes, the parameter inside the constructor should be the type of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You Class..

```
ClassText
{
   YourClass(String textVAlue)
   {
   }
 }
```

Your Form..

```
ClassText ct = new ClassText();
ct.YourClass(Textbox1.text);
```

Comment: This example doesnt help me... If I create new instance of form1. That will recreate all variables and controls. which doesnt make sense, all values are null at start. That will not give me the values I need from the main thread.